# how to wrap all class methods in a class in timeout wrappers

Tags: ruby, methods, timeout, metaprogramming, alias

I'm trying to create a class method that will put a timeout wrapper around other class methods.

```
class FooBar

  def self.slow_add(a,b,c)
    sleep 1
    a + b + c
  end

  LIST = [:slow_add]

  class << self
    LIST.each do |x|
      alias_method "#{x}_without_timeout", "#{x}"
      define_method("#{x}_with_timeout") do |*args|
        timeout(4){self.send(x, *args)}
      end
      alias_method "#{x}", "#{x}_with_timeout"
    end
  end
end
```

However, the resulting timeout methods always times out, even though they shouldn't:

```
2.0.0p353 :152 >   FooBar.slow_add_without_timeout(1, 2, 3)
 => 6 
2.0.0p353 :153 > FooBar.slow_add_with_timeout(1, 2, 3)
Timeout::Error: execution expired
...
...
2.0.0p353 :156 >   FooBar.slow_add(1, 2, 3)
Timeout::Error: execution expired
...
...
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's important that you're able to send a timeout message to your class, I would recommend creating an auxillary class that would wrap every method call in a timeout block and forward the message onto the original reference object. Something like this:

```
require 'timeout'

class TimeoutHandler
  attr_reader :seconds, :object
  def initialize(object, seconds)
    @seconds = seconds
    @object = object
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    Timeout::timeout(seconds){ object.send(name, *args, &block) }
  end
end
```

You would create instance of the `TimeoutHandler` like this:

```
class FooBar
  class << self
    def timeout(seconds = 4)
      TimeoutHandler.new(self, seconds)
    end
  end
end
```

So then anytime you need to interrupt a message with a timeout block, you simply call `timeout` on it first:

```
FooBar.timeout.slow_add(1, 2, 3)
```

You could write the `timeout` method in a mixin to be included in classes where you need this functionality.

However, all of this seems very contrived to me, and I would need a pretty good reason to implement it rather than just using the much simpler `Timeout::timeout { FooBar.slow_add(1, 2, 3) }`, which doesn't require any additional implementation.

Comment: this sounds like a great solution.  Would you be able to tell me why my original solution effectively causes a stack overflow though?(removing the call to the sleep method makes that more obvious when the methods are called in irb).  There's something about alias_method that I must be missing.

Comment: You're setting up a recursion by aliasing back to `x`. Calls to `x` get sent back to `x` ad infinitum.